# Autofs is forgetting mount points

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6, automount, autofs

I have a set of mount points which I use autofs to access. They have been around for quite some time, and in systems I've inherited running CentOS6 admins before me have implemented cronjobs restarting autofs conditionally if certain mountpoints are missing.

I've started setting up new CentOS7 systems using the same mountpoints and even though the autofs setup is brand new with new versions of everything and sssd replacing traditional ldap lookups and such autofs is still showing the same symptoms.

The problems I see are not in `/net` but other than that [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/368503) very old issue on redhat seem to be very similar to mine. Downgrading as suggested in the article is unfortunately not an option as CentOS7.5 only have 1 version of autofs (namely 5.0.7-83.el7) in the repos.

The mount points are available to autofs in such a way that I can query automount and get the proper record back:

```
# automount -m sss auto_projects | grep project1
project1    /subproj1 -noatime nfsserver:/volum/proj1_subproj1 /subproj2 -noatime nfsserver:/volum/proj1_subproj2 /subproj3 -noatime nfsserver:/volum/proj1_subproj3 /subproj4 -noatime nfsserver:/volum/proj1_subproj4 /subproj5 -noatime nfsserver:/volum/proj1_subproj5
```

When autofs is freshly started everything works as it should, I can browse `/projects/project1` and see `subproj1` through `5`.

After a little while (sometimes hours, sometimes days) however if I do `ls` in `/projects/project1` only one of the `subproj`s is still there. Trying to `cd` into any of the other folders (to trigger a mount) renders `-bash: cd: subprojX: No such file or directory`.

In the logs I'll see automount logging rows like:

```
expiring path /projects/project1
umount_multi: path /projects/project1 incl 1
umount_multi_triggers: umount offset /projects/project1/subprojX
umount_autofs_offset: offset /projects/project1/subprojX not mounted
rmdir_path: lstat of subprojX failed
[... more subprojs ...]
some offset mounts still present under /projects/project1
couldn't complete expire of /projects/project1
dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 853
1 remaining in /projects
```

If I don't start `autofs` with the `--force` option to `automount` I will not be able to recover from this. A `systemctl restart autofs` will hang and time out. With the `--force` option the service is restartable and will recover the mountpoints until they vanish again.

Mounting manually works as expected.

I think this is a bug in `autofs`, but I need help pinpointing / proving that. And perhaps also some help in creating a bug report...

How can I cure `autofs` from its apparent dementia?